# Чи можна сказати "викрили в дискримінації"?

Tags: вживання-слів, керування-відмінками

В [одному інтернет-виданні](http://nc4.info/business/211526-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97_%D0%B6%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) натрапила на такий заголовок: "Модні бренди викрили в дискримінації жінок".
Згідно зі [Словником української мови онлайн](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9240&page=325), слово викривати має такі значення:

> **ВИКРИВА́ТИ**, а́ю, а́єш, недок., ВИ́КРИТИ, ию, иєш, док.
>
> 1. кого, що. Виявляти приховане, злочинні чи негативні дії або причетність
>    кого-небудь до цих дій. Вже й дощі почали накрапати. І хто знає, чи не
>    розмиють вони як-небудь випадково землю під стіною й не викриють
>    нашого підкопу? А прокопано було вже доволі (В. Винниченко); Я повинен
>    був .. допомогти викрити зрадника (Ю. Яновський).
> 2. що. Робити відомим, засуджуючи (хиби, неправильність у чому-небудь, чиїсь дії і т. ін.). Письменник Франсуа Рабле викриває і таврує вади
>    сучасного йому суспільства (з публіц. літ.).
> 3. що. Розкривати, показувати щось приховане. Знала [Любов], що червоніє, як дівчина, викриває свою приховану радість (Іван Ле); Вона
>    вже мусить сама викрити своє ймення (Леся Українка); Наука викрила
>    колосальні закони природи (В. Підмогильний).

Згідно з керуванням, вказаним у словнику, це дієслово вимагає знахідного відмінка іменника, але вжито прийменникову форму місцевого. Чи прийнятна така будова словосполучення?
[Інше видання](https://ua.korrespondent.net/business/companies/3959490-modni-brendy-vykryly-v-dyskryminatsii-zhinok) також опублікувало статтю з тією ж назвою, але за кілька годин змінило її на "Модні бренди звинуватили у дискримінації жінок". Та дієслово *звинуватити* не є синонімом до *викрити*. Отже, як можна перефразувати речення зі збереженням вкладеного змісту?

Comment: «Викривати в _чомусь_» — це місцевий відмінок, а не родовий.

Comment: А, я зрозумів, Ви мали на увазі, що «жінок» у родовому (що додатком слова «викрили» є «модні бренди», а не «жінок», але речення побудоване так, що «жінок» помилково сприймається додатком слова «викрили»).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У цьому реченні виходить так:

> Модні бренди викрили / звинуватили (кого?, що?) жінок; викрили (в чому?) у дискримінації (хоча можна поставити і логічне питання *де?*).

Проте, виходячи із самого речення *"Модні бренди звинуватили у дискримінації жінок"*, можна зрозуміти його по-різному. Наприклад, модні бренди звинуватили жінок, які дискримінують когось (чиїсь права), і на цьому їх "зловили" (а як наслідок - звинуватили).

Однак, якщо прочитати статтю, то розуміємо, що мова йде про жінок, які не є рівноправними в оплаті праці, тобто отримують менше грошей, ніж чоловіки, проте роботу виконують однакову. Тому тут йдеться про вину (звинувачення) самих брендів, які й платять жінкам, порівняно з чоловіками, мало.

Вважаю, що тут є *стилістична помилка*, а саме неправильна побудова речення. Краще можна написати так:

> **"Жінки як об’єкт дискримінації у модних брендах"**.

Висновок: жінок не звинуватили у дискримінації, бо вони самі є постраждалими від цього явища.

Таким чином зміст збережено, а речення перефразовано. Так відбувається уникнення явища двозначності.